# JSTL foreach Help

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there a way to write this Java code as pure JSTL?

```
    for(int g = 0; g < eval.getCriterionGroupCount(); g++{
        //processing
        for(int c = 1; c < eval.getGroups().get(g).getCriterionCount() + 9; c++){
         //processing
        }
    }
```

- eval is an instance of a class
- getCriterionGroupCount returns an int
- getGroups returns an ArrayList
- getCriterionCount returns an int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go

```
 <c:forEach var="g" begin="0" end="${eval.criterionGroupCount}" step ="1">

   <c:forEach var="c" begin="1" end="${eval.groups[g].criterionCount + 9}" step ="1">

   </c:forEach>    

 </c:forEach>
```

Assuming `eval` is available through pageContext/request/session/servletContext